# Get the value of a json array where the key has a & in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON string that looks as follows.

```
{
    "Building": [ "Roofing", "Builders", ],
    "Rims & Tires": [ "Tire Fitter", ]
}
```

How would you get value from the "Rims & Tires" as the & seems to through off my javascript.

This is the code I have to use, the javascript needs to be in a string as it comes from a php file.

```
var result = "{"Building": ["Roofing", "Builders", ],"Rims & Tires": ["Tire Fitter", ]}";

$.each(result["Rims & Tires"], function(key1, value1) {
  console.log("" + value1);
});
```

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: It's a javascript object, not a string.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, changed it before you've commented (I've came back from the darkened path I was on).

Comment: OP, when you fix the obvious missing `)`, which I assume is just a typo when transposing the question, your code should (and does: https://jsfiddle.net/bd9mtq82/) work absolutely fine. Please check the console for issues.

Comment: The value is not being returned as the & in the `result["Rims & Tires"]` causes it to fail and not find the value. It tries to look for it in `result["Rims"]` instead.

Comment: Is there a reason you use jquery to loop through the array? result["Rims & Tires"].forEach(function(val){ console.log(val)}); not working?

Comment: `$.each( result["Rims & Tires"], function( key1, value1 ) {
  console.log(""+value1);
})`<<< missing )

Comment: Strongly suspect that the name of a JSON property should not contain spaces. See http://www.json.org/

Comment: If returned from a JSON call then indeed it is not valid JSON, but IS a valid JavaScript object as it is written in the example, except the trailing commas which will confuse some browsers

Comment: @VanquishedWombat nope, spaces are fine. A bigger problem would be the trailing `,` after the last items of the arrays

Comment: Thank - will leave my [incorrect] comment in place for other future readers.

Comment: It's funny how many people have learned something from this simple typo question....

Comment: @DanFromGermany you should have left your answer up - it was accurate, clear and valid.

Comment: Please see the updated code that I copy and pasted from my source in the exact format it is in. Thanks

Comment: It's not a valid JSON string if you have the extra commas like `{foo:[a,b,]}` instead of `{foo:[a,b]}`.You need to either a) revise your PHP or b) post-process the string you get from the response to get rid of the invalid `,`

Comment: It looks like you have a PHP loop with `echo $val . ','` instead of simply using the safe `echo json_encode($everything);`.
@VanquishedWombat It's np I leave it "hidden". I also didn't see the trailing `,` at first, maybe they were not in the question yet.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `result` is a string, and not an object. To convert a JSON string to an object, you can use `JSON#parse`. However, Your JSON string is invalid, and needs some cleaning. Remove the extra comma before the last bracket in each array.

In addition, change the wrapping comma `"` to `'` because otherwise, you'll get an `Invalid or unexpected token` error.

Before:

```
var result = "{"Building": ["Roofing", "Builders", ],"Rims & Tires": ["Tire Fitter", ]}";
```

After:

```
var result = '{"Building": ["Roofing", "Builders"],"Rims & Tires": ["Tire Fitter"]}';
```

Now the string is a valid string, and a valid JSON, and you can parse it to an object, and then access the inner array, using the brackets notation:

```js
var result = '{"Building": ["Roofing", "Builders"],"Rims & Tires": ["Tire Fitter"]}';

// parse the string
var resultObject = JSON.parse(result);

// iterate using forEach or if you must use jquery $.each
resultObject['Rims & Tires'].forEach(function(value, index) {
  console.log(index, value);
});
```